# javascript: my sound only plays once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I made a skill for my game called Blitz. Its functionality is that you strike your opponent 3 times within 6 seconds.

I added sound files to the skill so you can have hearing cues on what you did so you don't necessarily have to read a text log. The problem i'm having though is when I hit my opponent 2 or more times, the sound file only plays once, not twice.

For example: This works - Hit, Miss, Hit. 
For example: This does not work - Hit, Hit (no sound), Miss (sound)

Why is it skipping or not playing?

```
// BLITZ SKILL 

document.getElementById("blitz").addEventListener('click', function() {
    atbReset();
    DB();
    RET();
    window.setTimeout(function() { blitzskill() }, 1000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { blitzskill() }, 2000);
    window.setTimeout(function() { blitzskill() }, 3000);
});

function blitzskill(){
    var criticalRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    var precisionRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * cs.precision + 1);
    var npcParryRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * ds.parry + 1);
    var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * cs.strength * 1);

        if (character.energy <= 4) {
            addMessage("Not enough energy!")    
            return;
            }
        if (precisionRoll < npcParryRoll) {
            addMessage("The Dragon evaded your attack!");
            character.energy -= 5;
            miss.play(); // PLAY MISS SOUND
            }
        else if (damage - ds.armor <= 0) {
            character.energy -= 5;
            addMessage("Your opponents armor withstood your attack!");
            armor.play(); // PLAY MISS/ARMOR SOUND
            }   
        else if (cs.critical >= criticalRoll) {
            damage *= 2;
            damage -= ds.armor;
            dragon.hp -= damage;
            character.energy -= 5;
            document.getElementById("npchp").innerHTML = dragon.hp;
            addMessage("Critical Strike! Dragon suffers " + damage + " hp!")
            swoosh.play(); // PLAY HIT SOUND
            }   
        else {  
            dragon.hp -= damage;
            damage -= ds.armor;
            document.getElementById("npchp").innerHTML = dragon.hp;
            addMessage("You hit the dragon for " + damage + " hp!");
            character.energy -= 5;
            swoosh.play(); // PLAY HIT SOUND
            }
            document.getElementById("energy").innerHTML = character.energy;
};
```

Comment: Where are you getting swoosh - can you set up a fiddle without your game logic code

Comment: swoosh is just a sound file I used to play for hitting my opponent. I added up the setTimeOut to 2.5 seconds apart each and that fixed it, so it has to do with the sound file already playing the 2nd time around.

Comment: Hmm..what's that `setTimeout` doing there? Do you really have to call `blitzskill` three times when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
swoosh.pause();// ensure sound is not already playing 
swoosh.currentTime = 0; //reset time
swoosh.play(); // PLAY HIT SOUND
```

All I'm doing is adding logic to ensure you call play at the sound start

Comment: My sound does play at the start, its when it plays the 2nd time if I already hit my opponent that it does not play at all.

Comment: @user2763154 Try to add a fiddle because this is the only thing I can suggest without being able to test the case

Comment: Actually the code you gave me fixed the issue. It was the sound file already playing so it didn't play a 2nd time around. Thank you sir :)